# Casting Whole Number Portion of Double (2.0) to Int is Producing a Strange Result in C Program

Tags: c, casting, floating-point

***Problem solved, see the comment thread for explanation. Basically, what I was printing was NOT the actual value but an approximation. I wasn't aware of this behavior as I'm new to C, but upon printing the number with more decimal places it turns out it is not 2.000000 but really 1.99999999999990407673. I'll go put on my dunce hat and sit in the corner and read K&R for the rest of the day now...***

I'm at a loss for the behavior I'm seeing in this C program. I'm trying to build up a decimal-to-fraction converter, and I knew there would be some odd things to look out for when dealing with floating-point numbers, but this one doesn't seem to fit the mold of other questions I've browsed on Stack Overflow and through Google.

So, here is what is happening. I pass the number 3.642 to my function dec_to_frac. Here is the relevant portion from main():

```
void dec_to_frac(double dec);

int main() {

  double dec_1 = 3.642;

  dec_to_frac(dec_1);
```

I'm going about converting the decimal to a fraction by first truncating the whole number part using the fact that casts from double to int truncate the fractional part of a double.

```
void dec_to_frac(double dec) {

  /*
  * Uses the fact that assinging a double to int truncates the decimal portion. So,
  * if 3.64 is the dec, whole will hold 3
  */
  int whole = dec;
```

Then, I get the decimal portion of the number by subtracting the whole from the decimal passed in.

```
/*
* By subtracting the whole number portion from the decimal, we get the leftover 
* decimal portion. Ex. if dec is 3.64, whole is 3, so decimal holds 0.64.
*/
double decimal = dec - whole;
```

All of that works fine. Where the problem arises is as I loop through the decimal portion, cutting off each decimal digit each loop by multiplying it by 10. Here is the entire loop:

```
int i, whole_dec, temp;

whole_dec = 0;

// loops until decimal is less than the PRECISION defined at the top of the program
for (i = 0; decimal > PRECISION; i++) {

  /*
  * Moves the decimal place to the right. Ex. 0.64 becomes 6.4
  */
  decimal *= 10; 

  /*
  * temp is an int, so this should remove the whole number portion of the decimal.
  * Ex. if decimal is 6.4, temp will be 6.
  */
  temp = decimal;

  /*
  * whole_dec holds the whole number representation of the decimal thus far.
  * Ex. 0.64 is decimal at top of loop, becomes 6.4 after decimal *= 10, temp is 6, so 6
  * is added to whole_dec after whole decimal is multiplied by a power of 10.
  */
  whole_dec = whole_dec * 10 + temp;

  /*
  * temp holds the whole number portion of decimal, so this cuts off the whole number portion
  * leaving only the decimal portion. Ex. if decimal is 6.4, temp will be 6, so 6.4 - 6 = 0.4, the
  * decimal portion for the next loop.
  */
  decimal -= temp;
}
```

Now, all goes according to plan until I reach the last digit of 3.642. Here are some print statements showing the progress of the for loop:

```
TOP LOOP

Before [decimal *= 10],   decimal =   0.642000
After  [decimal *= 10],   decimal =   6.420000
After  [temp = decimal],  temp    =   6
Before [decimal -= temp], decimal =   6.420000
                          temp    =   6
After  [decimal -= temp], decimal =   0.420000


TOP LOOP

Before [decimal *= 10],   decimal =   0.420000
After  [decimal *= 10],   decimal =   4.200000
After  [temp = decimal],  temp    =   4
Before [decimal -= temp], decimal =   4.200000
                          temp    =   4
After  [decimal -= temp], decimal =   0.200000


TOP LOOP

Before [decimal *= 10],   decimal =   0.200000
After  [decimal *= 10],   decimal =   2.000000
After  [temp = decimal],  temp    =   1
Before [decimal -= temp], decimal =   2.000000
                          temp    =   1
After  [decimal -= temp], decimal =   1.000000
```

Notice in the very last print block, that the decimal value is 2.000000 but when the following assignment occurs, temp is 1:

```
temp = decimal;
```

What is going on here? I tested this in main with constant values and the result was as expected:

```
int main() {

  double dec = 2.000000;
  int temp = dec;

  printf("%d\n", temp); // temp is 2 here, which I would expect
```

I can't understand why 2.000000 when assigned to int within my for loop produces a 1, but in main produces a 2! What am I missing?

Comment: are you sure this isn't some floating point number very close to `2` being rounded up to `2.000000` for display?

Comment: Can you please boil all of this down to a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @guest I was not aware that was a possibility! I didn't even think about the fact that the number being displayed actually isn't the number that is stored. I'm still very new to C!

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @Daniel.Schroeder Like most real numbers, 0.2 isn't representable exactly in binary floating point. Increase the number of decimals in your output to see what's happening.

Comment: @Daniel.Schroeder, the usual computer representations of real numbers cannot exactly represent all numbers within their overall numeric range.  In fact, they can exactly represent only an infinitesimal subset of those numbers.  Decimal numbers 3.642, .642, .42, and .2 in particular are not exactly representable in the usual format with which type `double` is represented.

Comment: You guys are spot on, I just didn't ever read up enough on how the printed representation of floating point worked. The number is 1.9999....0407...  so now I totally see what's happening, thanks for the help!

Comment: Would you like to create an answer yourself? I think Q/A pairs are better than Q/comment pairs. And an answer inside the question makes the question ugly. With a bit of polished phrasing you might even harvest some upvoting. The topic seems interesting enough to me.

Comment: @Yunnosch I will definitely do that tomorrow, running out the door heading to work now!